# Getting data from ftp file directly into environment or as file r

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

Trying to get file from ftp server with HTTR and RCurl any method doesn't work.
Real case. User and password credentials are real.
First HTTR

```
library(httr)
GET(url = "ftp://77.72.135.237/2993309138_Tigres.xls", authenticate("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxx"),
    write_disk("~/Downloads/2993309138_Tigres.xls", overwrite = T))
#> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Second RCurl

```
library(RCurl)
my_data <- getURL(url = "ftp://77.72.135.237/2993309138_Tigres.xls", userpwd = "xxxxxx")
#> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding): embedded nul in string: 'ÐÏ\021à¡±\032á'
```

Is it server side bug or mine? :)

Comment: I posted an edit that removes your login information. Please do not post username/passwords for any services on Stack Overflow (or anywhere for that matter).

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have something to do with the encoding. Try like this (you'll have to fill in the authentication) :

```
library(httr)

content(
        GET(url = "ftp://77.72.135.237/2993309138_Tigres.xls",
            authenticate("...", "..."),
            write_disk("~/Downloads/2993309138_Tigres.xls", overwrite = T)
            ),
        type = "text/csv",
        as = "text",
        encoding = "WINDOWS-1251"
)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The same error
#> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors